# C# Cast List of MyType to List of objects

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I'm writing an application where I am required to use Reflection to call a method which has parameters of type MyObject.

```
Method (List<MyObject> input , out List<MyObject> output,..... );
```

Using reflection I send the parameter of type Object. How can I cast `List<MyObject>` to `List<object>`

```
var parameters = new Object[] { inputs, outputs, userPrams };
System.Type classType = typeof(MyClass);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
classType.InvokeMember(name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,null, instance, parameters);
```

In the code above both input and output are lists of type MyObject

I tried to Cast them to List of Objects but this doesn't work

```
x.Outputs = grOutputs as IList<object>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear, so I assumed the problem you're facing is the one you put in the title:

> **Cast List of MyType to List of objects**

As @Charles said, `IList<T>` and `List<T>` are not variant, so you can't cast `IList<DerivedClass>` to `IList<BaseClass>`. You have to create new `List<BaseClass>`.

There are many ways to do that, I think there are two you should consider:

1. You can use `Cast` and `ToList`, but it will require `using System.Linq`.

   ```
   var listOfStrings = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar" };
   var listOfObjects = listOfStrings.Cast<object>().ToList();
   ```
2. To avoid that, you can use `new List<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)` constructor. Because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, you can do following:

   ```
   var listOfStrings = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar" };
   var listOfObjects = new List<object>(listOfString);
   ```

Comment: Thanks 
the first option not working
but the second one Worked

Answer (score 4):

You might well want to do something like this:

```
var dogs = new List<Dog>();
var pets = (List<object>)dogs;
pets.Add(new Cat());
```

The C# language is heavily invested in you stop mixing cats and dogs like this.  It violates the hard guarantee that the list only ever contains dogs.  You'll have to do it like this instead:

```
var dogs = new List<Dog>();
var pets = new List<object>(dogs);
pets.Add(new Cat());
```

Which is fine, it creates a *new* list, one that no longer guarantees that it only ever contains dogs since it only promises that the list contains *object*.  Pretty useless, typically, you basically lose all knowledge of what the list contains.  Forcing you to write hunt-the-fox code that uses the *as* operator or Reflection to find the proper animal back.  Code that fails to do its job at run-time instead of the compiler telling you that its wrong code at build time, when you're still in the comfortable cubicle cocoon.

Which it did.

Answer (score 2):

`IList<T>` is not covariant, you would need to create a new list if you wanted `IList<object>`:

```
x.Outputs = grOutputs.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could try something like this :

```
var objList = myClassList.OfType<object>();
```

Comment: This isn't logically any different than any of the other mechanisms of achieving the same result from other answers, why do you think this is better?

Comment: @Preston: I thought that the use of the OfType<T> method could be relevant because it won't raise an "InvalidCastException", especially when trying to get the original class back. Sorry if my answer was to close from the others.

Comment: You should include that information in your answer, but in this case he's *not* trying to get the original class back, he's upcasting to `object`, which will never throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make your desired cast because, as others have written, collections in c# are not [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

You can either create a new list, or introduce a ListWrapper class like so:

```
public class ListWrapper<TOut, TIn> : IList<TOut> where TIn : class, TOut where TOut : class 
{
    readonly IList<TIn> list;

    public ListWrapper(IList<TIn> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        this.list = list;
    }

    #region IList<TOut> Members

    public int IndexOf(TOut item)
    {
        TIn itemIn = item as TIn;
        if (itemIn != item)
            return -1;
        return list.IndexOf(itemIn);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, TOut item)
    {
        list.Insert(index, (TIn)item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public TOut this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return list[index];
        }
        set
        {
            list[index] = (TIn)value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<TOut> Members

    public void Add(TOut item)
    {
        list.Add((TIn)item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(TOut item)
    {
        TIn itemIn = item as TIn;
        if (itemIn != item)
            return false;
        return list.Contains(itemIn);
    }

    public void CopyTo(TOut[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            array[arrayIndex] = item;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return list.IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(TOut item)
    {
        return list.Remove(item as TIn);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<TOut> Members

    public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            yield return item;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You might want to make the wrapper read-only since the setter could throw an exception if the incoming object is not of the inner list's item type.